# How to simulate a HOLD keydown event using pywin32?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, automation

I am trying to get this piece of python code to work on windows:

```
import win32process, win32con, win32gui, win32api, time

HWND = win32gui.GetActiveWindow()
win32api.PostMessage(HWND, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_SPACE, 0)
time.sleep(6)
win32api.PostMessage(HWND, win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_SPACE, 0)
```

It is supposed to simulate someone holding down the space key, but it does not work and does not provide any sort of error message. I believe I may be doing something wrong with HWND, but I am not sure if that is the case.. I would like the event to be sent to any active window that I select to choose.

Can you help?

---

Solved my problem by using ctypes and the user32.keybd_event method.

```
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(hexx[key], 0, 0, 0)      #Key is down
ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event(hexx[key], 0, 0x0002, 0) #Key is up
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use the raw pywin32? You can, for example, use pywinauto or SendKeys for this purpose.

Comment: @SWAPYAutomation SendKeys does not support the hold key event. I will check pywinauto.

Comment: pywinauto uses SendKey. Try to check that win32gui.GetActiveWindow() returns needed window.

Comment: Surely you'd be better off using `keybd_event`

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thanks, I came to that solution just as you answered my question. Best.