# Win32api: Press and Hold key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I'm looking for a way to press a key and hold it for a specific amount of time. I have tried:

```
# Method 1
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys

# Method 2
win32api.SendMessage

# Method 3
win32api.keybd_event
```

All of these methods, only seem to press a key once. I need to hold the key down.

I have looked at these resources: [python simulate keydown (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown), [win32api.keybd_event](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104590/win32api.keybd_event), [press-and-hold-with-pywin32 (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271761/how-to-emulate-press-and-hold-with-pywin32), [simulate-a-hold-keydown-event-using-pywin32 (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102875/how-to-simulate-a-hold-keydown-event-using-pywin32), [Vitual keystroke (Github)](https://gist.github.com/chriskiehl/2906125)

Comment: I use pynput for most of my keyboard manipulation

Comment: Is there a way to do it with Windows API?

Comment: i mean, it is doable from python, so i assumed that python options were on the table which work cross platform.  Im unaware of platform specific options.

Comment: It is unclear, what you expect to happen, or who you are interacting with. Different application types use different input systems, and a solution needs to cater to the input system the designated target application uses. Calling `keybd_event` for e.g. a game likely has no effect.

Comment: "Calling keybd_event for e.g. a game likely has no effect."? do you know of anyway to execute key up/down, that is compatible with a game?

Comment: Writing a keyboard driver would certainly be an option. Input will look like it's coming from a real device, making it harder for the application to identify it as non-human input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use PyAutoGUI, this would do it:

```
import pyautogui
import time

def hold_key(key, hold_time):
    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < hold_time:
        pyautogui.keyDown(key)

hold_key('a', 5)
```

It will keep the 'a' key pressed for 5 seconds.

Comment: why not just to:  `time.sleep(hold_time)` ?  then do something like:  `keyDown(key) time.sleep(hold_time) keyUp(key)`

Comment: because that way it will just press once, wait your hold time, and then release...it won't keep pressing while sleeping

Comment: The key is not being held down, just repetitively pressed for 5 seconds.

Comment: I never used pyautogui before, but understanding the similar functionality of competition, there is both a press and release function for them, so you can do like shift-down, a, b, c, shift-up which would result in:  "ABC"